# Getting unique tuples out of a python set

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, tuples, unique

I currently have a set like the following:

```
{(a,b), (b,a), (c,b), (b,c)}
```

What I Would like to have is:

```
{(a,b), (c,b)}
```

As you may notice the duplicate values have been removed completely so that two tuples never have the same elements inside regardless of order.

How can I tell the set to disregard the order of the elements in the tuple and just check the values between the tuples?

Comment: Why not expected output it `{(b, a), (c, b)}`, or `{(a, b), (b, c)}`? Sets are not ordered, you have no guarantee in which order you'll access it's elements.

Comment: Mine was an example. I do not care which combination I get in return, I care that it is unique.

Comment: Have you considered creating your custom class and implementing `__hash__` method? If `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` are semantically equal there is no need to have them both in set in the first place. By overriding `__hash__` you can achieve that.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that, reason which I wrote here. Can you help?

Comment: @Con7e so do some research, there are plenty of tutorials on creating classes already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you've got a set `{c1, c2, c3, ...}`, where each `cN` is itself a collection of some sort.

If you don't care about the order of the elements in `cN`, but do care that it is unique (disregarding order), then `cN` should be a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)<sup>**1**</sup> rather than a `tuple`:

```
>>> orig = {("a", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("c", "b"), ("b", "c")}
>>> uniq = {frozenset(c) for c in orig}
>>> uniq
{frozenset(['b', 'a']), frozenset(['b', 'c'])}
```

As a general rule, choosing an appropriate data type from those provided by Python is going to be more straightforward than defining and maintaining custom classes.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> It can't be a `set`, because as a member of a larger `set` it needs to be hashable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather ugly, straightforward solution. You implement equality to treat `(2, 3)` and `(3, 2)` as the equal objects, you implement `__hash__` to disallow equal members in set. You access members as in assertions below.

I'm unhappy with how hashing function looks, but anyway - it's just proof of concept. Hopefully you'll find more elegant solution to calculate it without collisions.

```
class WhateverItIs(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ((self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b) or
        (self.a == other.b and self.b == other.a))
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted((self.a, self.b))))

o1 = WhateverItIs(2, 3)
o2 = WhateverItIs(3, 2)
o3 = WhateverItIs(4, 3)

assert {o1, o2, o3} in [{o1, o3}, {o2, o3}]
assert o1 == o2
assert o1.a == 2
assert o1.b == 3
assert o2.a == 3
assert o2.b == 2
assert o3.a == 4
assert o3.b == 3
```

Comment: Sorry, the solution with the frozensets is quite more readable :(

Comment: @Con7e yep, but "tuple values are always unique" was not part of specification :) .

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> aa = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'a')] 
>>> seen = set() 
>>> a = [seen.add((x,y)) for x,y in aa if (x,y) and (y,x) not in seen ]
>>> list(seen)
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing you can do is simply sort each `tuple` element (which makes the `tuple` a `list`), then cast back as a `tuple`, allowing it to be added to the set and maintaining the "hashable type" of `tuple`.

Example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> set_to_add_tuples_to = set()
>>> tuples_to_add_to_set = [(a,b), (b,a), (c,b), (b,c)]
>>> print(tuple_to_add_to_set)
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> for tup in tuples_to_add_to_set:
...    tup = tuple(sorted(tup))
...    set_to_add_tuples_to.add(tup)
>>> print(set_to_add_tuples_to)
{(1, 2), (2, 3)}
```